# Use custom action in wix bootstrapper | Wixsharp

Tags: custom-action, bootstrapper, wixsharp

I have a simple bootstrapper installer in wixsharp and
I'd like to use a custom action like that:

```
 bootstrapper.AddWixFragment("CustomActions",
            new ManagedAction(CustomAction.MyAction, Return.check, When.Before, Step.InstallInitialize, Condition.NOT_BeingRemoved, Sequence.InstallUISequence));
```

But I get error cannot convert type `ManagedAction` to type `XElement`

from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615043/how-can-i-show-information-from-wix-custom-actions-in-burn-managed-bootstrapper), it seems I can use custom action in WIX

How can i use custom action in wix bootstrapper in wixsharp?

Thx

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018511/how-to-use-customaction-in-wix-bundle